# Center a view inside of an UITableViewCell? Looks centered in the UI hierarchy, but not in the actual app?

Tags: swift, uitableview, user-interface, uiview, centering

I'm trying to center a custom UIView in a UITableViewCell. Something fairly basic imo. I used this code to create the UIView, I found it here on stackoverflow:

```
class SkeletonView: UIView {

    var startLocations : [NSNumber] = [-1.0,-0.5, 0.0]
    var endLocations : [NSNumber] = [1.0,1.5, 2.0]

    var gradientBackgroundColor : CGColor = UIColor(white: 0.85, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    var gradientMovingColor : CGColor = UIColor(white: 0.75, alpha: 1.0).cgColor

    var movingAnimationDuration : CFTimeInterval = 0.8
    var delayBetweenAnimationLoops : CFTimeInterval = 1.0


    lazy var gradientLayer : CAGradientLayer = {

        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        gradientLayer.colors = [
            gradientBackgroundColor,
            gradientMovingColor,
            gradientBackgroundColor
        ]
        gradientLayer.locations = self.startLocations
        self.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
        return gradientLayer
    }()


    func startAnimating(){
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "locations")
        animation.fromValue = self.startLocations
        animation.toValue = self.endLocations
        animation.duration = self.movingAnimationDuration
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)


        let animationGroup = CAAnimationGroup()
        animationGroup.duration = self.movingAnimationDuration + self.delayBetweenAnimationLoops
        animationGroup.animations = [animation]
        animationGroup.repeatCount = .infinity
        self.gradientLayer.add(animationGroup, forKey: animation.keyPath)
    }

    func stopAnimating() {
        self.gradientLayer.removeAllAnimations()
    }
}
```

Then I just added a view to my cell xib, centered horizontally, leading edge +15, top +15 and bottom +15 (with priority 900 so that autolayout doesn't freak out about the height being 320 instead of its calculated value of 320.1). This way it is centered in the xib preview.

[image]

When running the app it looks like this, as you can see there is a gap on the left side, but not on the right side, so its not centered:

[image: uita]

But then when I take a look at the UI hierarchy, it is centered?!
[image]

Comment: show your xib file ... where you add constraint

Comment: i think you add leading to margin instead of edge

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the xib file.

Comment: but its not showing constraints that you added

Comment: i need to see the constraint ... leading and trailing constraint

Comment: Yes, I just added a screenshot of that.

Comment: You're missing the trailing constraint, and also, you don't need the Align Center X constraint.

Comment: I've answered my own question below, and adding a trailing constraint is the same as setting horizontal center, at least if you want leading and trailing constraints to be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the problem. The UIView was placed correctly, however the gradientLayer I placed overtop was getting a wrong size. So I added the line

```
gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
```

in the layoutSubviews function inside the skeleton UIView class.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Remove `centered horizontally` contraint and add `trailing constraint` to 15 will resolve your issue

its good enough on my side

Comment: This should work though. This works in another cell I made. Adding a trailing constraint of 15 gives the same result.

Comment: do you have teamviewer ?

Comment: or send me this sample ... i will see whats the issue or i can connect via teamviewer to solve it

Comment: No, not going to install it for this either, thanks for offering the help though. Cant you create a quick project, add a table view, add a cell and use this UIView I provided?

Comment: Hmm super weird

Comment: thats why i was saying to use teamviewer or send project